# Склонение "Аскания-Нова"

Tags: склонение, ономастика

Есть в Херсонской области такой заповедник — Аскания-Нова. Но что-то меня заклинило: как обе части этого слова склоняются по падежам? Точнее, склоняются обе части или одна из них?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сразу скажу, что общих правил для топонимов не существует. Надо смотреть в словарях.
К сожалению, легкодоступные словари расходятся в рекомендациях.
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%E0%F1%EA%E0%ED%E8%FF*&all=x
Аскания-Нова, другие формы не употр. (Лопатин)
Аскания-Нова, Аскании-Нова (запов., Херсонск. обл., Украина) (СИС).
Встречается еще и вариант со склонением обеих частей (и лично я внутренне тяготею к нему).
И, наконец, склонение по варианту прилагательного: Аскании Новой во всех падежах, кроме И. и В.
Фантастичные варианты отбрасываю.

Если у кого есть топонимический справочник, хорошо бы уточнить именно в таковом.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, склоняются обе части слова, потому что дословно звучит "Аскания-Нова" образовалось без всяких соединительных морфем. Фактически это два разных слова, написанные через дефис. Только вот, по-моему, слово *"нова"* (от лат. *nova* [ед. число]) не склоняется. Так что склоняем только Асканию.     
Подтверждение своей мысли нашел на википедии: "Самое распространённое растение **в Аскании-Нова** это ковыль."